# how to create a .csv file to generate the coordinates along the path between two annotations in map in iOS?

Tags: csv, ios5, mapkit

I have created a mapView in my app. I am developing for iOS5.
Here I have to plot two points and draw a route between them.
I read many tutorial but they use there pre-defined .csv file, which contains the coordinates of the path between to points.
Can we create a file which can generate all the coordinates along the path between the two annotations plotted.
Please help me with this.